# My md-tab-nav-bar is blank

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am trying to implement a dynamic navbar using Angular's Material design.
However I can't seem to figure out why its not displaying correctly..
Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/fv9l2i
Could someone help me figure out where I am messing up?

navBar.comp.html:

```
    <nav md-tab-nav-bar>
      <a md-tab-link
         *ngFor="let link of navLinks"
         [routerLink]="navLinks.link"
         routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
         [active]="rla.isActive">
        {{navLinks.label}}
      </a>
    </nav>

    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    Current Area:
    Fun  &nbsp;<md-slide-toggle
    class="example-margin"
    [color]="color"
    [checked]="checked"
    (change)="onChange($event)">Information</md-slide-toggle>
```

navBar.comp.ts

```
    import { Component, OnInit, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';

    @Injectable()
    @Component({
      selector: 'nav-Bar',
        templateUrl: 'navBar.component.html'
    })

    export class NavBarComponent implements OnInit {

        navLinks: any[];
        activeLinkIndex = 0;
        constructor(private router: Router) {
          this.navLinks = [
          {label: 'Profile', link: '/profile/', index: '0'},
          {label: 'Notification', link: '/notifications/', index: '1'},
          {label: 'Home', link: '', index: '3'},
          {label: 'My Cards', link: '/cards/', index: '4'},
          {label: 'Create a Card', link: '/post/', index: '5'},
          {label: 'Logout', link: '/login/', index: '6'},
        ];
        }

        ngOnInit() {
            // get posts from secure api end point
        //    this.profileService.getUser()
        //        .subscribe(author => {
        //            this.author = author;
          //      });
        }
    }
```

app.routing.ts

```
    ﻿import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
    import { LoginComponent } from './login/index';
    import { HomeComponent } from './home/index';
    import { ProfileComponent } from './profile/index';
    import { CreatePostComponent } from './createPost/index';
    import { UserPostsComponent } from './userposts/index';
    import { RegisterComponent } from './register/index';
    import { NotificationComponent } from './notification/index';
    import { NavBarComponent } from './navBar/index';
    import { AuthGuard } from './_guards/index';

    const appRoutes: Routes = [
        { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
        { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
        { path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
        { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
        { path: 'post', component: CreatePostComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
        { path: 'cards', component: UserPostsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
        { path: 'notifications', component: NotificationComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
        // otherwise redirect to home
        { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
    ];

    export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

Comment: Fixed this myself, ended up doing: <nav md-tab-nav-bar aria-label="Navigation links">
    <a md-tab-link
        *ngFor="let routeLink of routeLinks; let i = index"
         [routerLink]="routeLink.link"
         [active]="activeLinkIndex === i"
         (click)="activeLinkIndex = i">
         {{routeLink.label}}
     </a>
</nav>

Comment: and changed: navLinks to routeLinks

Answer (score 0):

You should use `{{link.label}}` instead of `{{navLinks.label}}`

You should update `[routerLink]="navLinks.link"` to `[routerLink]="link.link"`